# Use continuous variables in State-Space block OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have created a model in OpenModelica that assembles state space matrices using an interpolation table. The matrices are created using a table that accepts one input and 39 outputs (13 eigenvalues, 13 system inputs and 13 system outputs). I can assemble the matrices just fine, but when assigning them to the State Space block I get the following error:

> [ZapuniInterpolation: 53:52-53:57]: Component A of variability parameter has binding 'ssA' of higher variability continuous.

The model is given by the code below:

```
block ZapuniInterpolation
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds modelDef(table = [180.0, 0.0, 0.125639618, 0.122496368, 0.152595123, 1.30134654, 7.03518772, 10.1638193, 11.777113, 12.5243101, 21.683424, 27.5360508, 34.4655838, 34.1353836, -0.000156808334, 0.000567958435, -6.16513252e-06, 5.07716331e-05, 0.000295116516, -0.00226303029, 1.72715359e-05, -2.76345825e-05, -0.000384722595, -1.60172176e-05, 2.38217144e-05, 8.43528748e-06, 2.26263523e-05, -0.0392020416, -0.0412239838, 0.000444312775, -0.00735736036, 0.083243988, 0.00416324186, 0.00528137589, -0.012360487, 1.24845228e-05, -0.196934738, 6.53376694e-05, -7.1772345e-07, -0.047993618; 182.5, 0.0, 0.12338031, 0.121614441, 0.152516403, 1.28446889, 7.03372765, 10.160368, 11.7592869, 12.5243101, 24.4601326, 27.5334625, 34.4655838, 32.8034935, -0.000155028641, 0.000569061768, -1.06752777e-05, 4.43576736e-05, 0.000292540131, -0.00226327395, 1.87270737e-05, -2.94425335e-05, -0.000384721771, -1.95333481e-05, 2.38186722e-05, 8.43502998e-06, 2.18605156e-05, -0.038757122, -0.0399122047, 0.000745555359, -0.00661621618, 0.080380722, 0.00384176278, 0.00474613094, -0.010696907, 1.03946018e-05, -0.187355469, 0.000304825897, -3.04758026e-07, -0.0856405334; 185.0, 0.0, 0.121165268, 0.120708992, 0.152441833, 1.26705885, 7.03220701, 10.1565781, 11.7394562, 12.5243101, 26.2911625, 27.5308762, 34.4655838, 33.3992195, -0.000153284882, 0.000568685425, -4.0209774e-05, 3.89236832e-05, 0.000290123566, -0.00226349735, 2.0346014e-05, -3.14919395e-05, -0.000384720856, -2.75364189e-05, 2.39696522e-05, 8.43503952e-06, 1.46955872e-05, -0.0383211823, -0.0385091896, 0.00271969485, -0.00597921848, 0.0775424423, 0.00357709074, 0.00436138248, -0.00955755329, 8.97015572e-06, -0.137678406, 0.000970456665, -8.64766174e-07, -0.156308731; 187.5, 0.0, 0.118988342, 0.119786552, 0.152369507, 1.24918771, 7.0306282, 10.1524391, 11.7177658, 12.5243092, 26.049839, 27.5282478, 34.4655838, 37.3313332, -0.000151576111, 0.000570432922, 2.22414017e-05, 3.42602654e-05, 0.000287870667, -0.00226369929, 2.21327553e-05, -3.37703247e-05, -0.000384719849, -3.28333435e-05, 2.40614624e-05, 8.43494415e-06, 6.49287128e-06, -0.0378939934, -0.0372608452, -0.00145591199, -0.00542455482, 0.074719574, 0.00335672474, 0.00408232164, -0.00875357533, 7.95372009e-06, -0.080245285, 0.000683899231, 4.3715094e-07, -0.196699677; 190.0, 0.0, 0.116858894, 0.118837822, 0.152297958, 1.23091626, 7.02899122, 10.1479139, 11.6941319, 12.5243092, 24.9532948, 27.5255089, 34.4655838, 43.7087631, -0.000149901413, 0.000571410095, 8.67566872e-06, 3.02129364e-05, 0.000285783508, -0.00226387715, 2.41047344e-05, -3.62895241e-05, -0.000384718781, -3.62359619e-05, 2.40104408e-05, 8.43495083e-06, 3.14631987e-06, -0.0374753189, -0.0359707489, -0.000549157532, -0.0049361062, 0.0719031982, 0.00317143512, 0.00388165021, -0.00817939949, 7.20596743e-06, -0.0537428932, 0.000341564392, 1.62058945e-07, -0.2088992; 195.0, 0.0, 0.112727142, 0.116876053, 0.152152176, 1.19337523, 7.02551937, 10.1374197, 11.639926, 12.5243092, 22.4547005, 27.5198441, 34.4655838, 63.5006485, -0.000146650772, 0.000572308289, 3.85471559e-06, 2.35291004e-05, 0.000282106537, -0.00226414824, 2.87340622e-05, -4.21810608e-05, -0.00038471637, -4.2829483e-05, 2.39550076e-05, 8.43493652e-06, 1.15650666e-06, -0.0366626587, -0.0333576317, -0.00022747081, -0.0041120615, 0.0662582474, 0.0028797617, 0.00365292263, -0.00749141979, 6.22078133e-06, -0.0335395622, 0.00014459668, 7.19030685e-08, -0.2181745; 200.0, 0.0, 0.10876281, 0.114828865, 0.151995438, 1.15478432, 7.02172279, 10.1242056, 11.5731678, 12.5243082, 20.1688595, 27.5138836, 34.4655838, 97.7778931, -0.000143526184, 0.000572750549, 2.4388926e-06, 1.82274666e-05, 0.000279082581, -0.00226427436, 3.46423569e-05, -4.95841827e-05, -0.000384713623, -5.03695107e-05, 2.39311123e-05, 8.4349184e-06, 1.23468935e-06, -0.0358815079, -0.030764555, -0.000133495087, -0.00343931985, 0.0605537033, 0.00266271996, 0.00360132694, -0.00721686459, 5.66029549e-06, -0.0255758495, 8.98340149e-05, 4.8260746e-08, -0.220523834]) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = { 0, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Real [13] omega2={modelDef.y[1], modelDef.y[2], modelDef.y[3], modelDef.y[4], modelDef.y[5], modelDef.y[6], modelDef.y[7], modelDef.y[8], modelDef.y[9], modelDef.y[10], modelDef.y[11], modelDef.y[12], modelDef.y[13]}; 
// ------
  Real [13] Ba={modelDef.y[14], modelDef.y[15], modelDef.y[16], modelDef.y[17], modelDef.y[18], modelDef.y[19], modelDef.y[20], modelDef.y[21], modelDef.y[22], modelDef.y[23], modelDef.y[24], modelDef.y[25], modelDef.y[26]}; 
// ------
  Real [13] Ca={modelDef.y[27], modelDef.y[28], modelDef.y[29], modelDef.y[30], modelDef.y[31], modelDef.y[32], modelDef.y[33], modelDef.y[34], modelDef.y[35], modelDef.y[36], modelDef.y[37], modelDef.y[38], modelDef.y[39]}; 
// ------
  Real [13] damping={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Real [26, 26] ssA = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1; 
     - omega2[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, - omega2[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, - omega2[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, - omega2[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[7], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[7], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[9], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[9], 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[10], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[10], 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[11], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[11], 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[12], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[12], 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[13] ];
// ------
  Real [26, 1] ssB = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; Ba[1]; Ba[2]; Ba[3]; Ba[4]; Ba[5]; Ba[6]; Ba[7]; Ba[8]; Ba[9]; Ba[10]; Ba[11]; Ba[12]; Ba[13]]; 
// ------
  Real [3, 26] ssC = [Ca[1], Ca[2], Ca[3], Ca[4], Ca[5], Ca[6], Ca[7], Ca[8], Ca[9], Ca[10], Ca[11], Ca[12], Ca[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     Ba[1], Ba[2], Ba[3], Ba[4], Ba[5], Ba[6], Ba[7], Ba[8], Ba[9], Ba[10], Ba[11], Ba[12], Ba[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Ba[1], Ba[2], Ba[3], Ba[4], Ba[5], Ba[6], Ba[7], Ba[8], Ba[9], Ba[10], Ba[11], Ba[12], Ba[13] ];
// ------
  Real [3, 1] ssD = [0; 
     0; 
     0];
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput tableInput annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 40}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-60, 40}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.StateSpace stateSpace(A=ssA, B=ssB, C=ssC, D=ssD, initType = Modelica.Blocks.Types.Init.NoInit) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput out1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {50, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput out2 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput out3 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {50, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ssInput annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-60, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  connect(modelDef.u, tableInput) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-12, 40}, {-60, 40}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(stateSpace.y[1], out1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{12, 0}, {20, 0}, {20, 20}, {50, 20}, {50, 20}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(stateSpace.y[2], out2) annotation(
    Line(points = {{12, 0}, {42, 0}, {42, 0}, {50, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(stateSpace.y[3], out3) annotation(
    Line(points = {{12, 0}, {20, 0}, {20, -20}, {50, -20}, {50, -20}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(stateSpace.u[1], ssInput) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-12, 0}, {-60, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
end ZapuniInterpolation;
```

Now I can obviously change all of the *Real* declarations to *parameter Real*, which solves the problem for the State-Space block. However then I cannot define the arrays *omega2, Ba, Ca* based on the interpolation table: the following error then occurs

> [ZapuniInterpolationTest: 6:3-6:229]: Component omega2 of variability parameter has binding '{modelDef.y[1], modelDef.y[2], modelDef.y[3], modelDef.y[4], modelDef.y[5], modelDef.y[6], modelDef.y[7], modelDef.y[8], modelDef.y[9], modelDef.y[10], modelDef.y[11], modelDef.y[12], modelDef.y[13]}' of higher variability continuous.

So my question is, what can I do to define the matrices using the interpolation table and use them in the State-Space block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly, you would like to use an input to compute the coefficients of a system matrix via a table for interpolation. This will result in `ssA` being variables.

The fundamental problem is that the parameters for the `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.StateSpace` have a lower variability compared to variables. Parameters are constant during a simulation, whereas variables change over time. In Modelica it is not possible to assign an expression to another expression with a lower variability. For more information on this see [Modelica Language Specification](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf), Section 3.8.

There are two solutions to this

1. Compute the parameters of the state-space block from parameters and constants only (for which the result will be constant over time).
2. Re-implement the state-space block without the restriction of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` being parameters. I think technically it is not a state-space anymore then, but that's nitpicking...

Option 1. does not seem to be helpful for you, so I will skip it.

Option 2. should be possible by adding the state-space equations directly in the model. This should be

```
  der(x) = ssA*x + ssB*{ssInput};
  y = ssC*x + ssD*{ssInput};
  out1 = y[1];
  out2 = y[2];
  out3 = y[3];
```

for your case. Additionally you will need to define `x` and `y` with

```
Real x[size(ssA,1)] "states";   
Real y[size(ssC,1)] "outputs";
```

and remove the original definition of the state-space block (and its connections).

This should result in the overall code:

```
block ZapuniInterpolation
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds modelDef(table = [180.0, 0.0, 0.125639618, 0.122496368, 0.152595123, 1.30134654, 7.03518772, 10.1638193, 11.777113, 12.5243101, 21.683424, 27.5360508, 34.4655838, 34.1353836, -0.000156808334, 0.000567958435, -6.16513252e-06, 5.07716331e-05, 0.000295116516, -0.00226303029, 1.72715359e-05, -2.76345825e-05, -0.000384722595, -1.60172176e-05, 2.38217144e-05, 8.43528748e-06, 2.26263523e-05, -0.0392020416, -0.0412239838, 0.000444312775, -0.00735736036, 0.083243988, 0.00416324186, 0.00528137589, -0.012360487, 1.24845228e-05, -0.196934738, 6.53376694e-05, -7.1772345e-07, -0.047993618; 182.5, 0.0, 0.12338031, 0.121614441, 0.152516403, 1.28446889, 7.03372765, 10.160368, 11.7592869, 12.5243101, 24.4601326, 27.5334625, 34.4655838, 32.8034935, -0.000155028641, 0.000569061768, -1.06752777e-05, 4.43576736e-05, 0.000292540131, -0.00226327395, 1.87270737e-05, -2.94425335e-05, -0.000384721771, -1.95333481e-05, 2.38186722e-05, 8.43502998e-06, 2.18605156e-05, -0.038757122, -0.0399122047, 0.000745555359, -0.00661621618, 0.080380722, 0.00384176278, 0.00474613094, -0.010696907, 1.03946018e-05, -0.187355469, 0.000304825897, -3.04758026e-07, -0.0856405334; 185.0, 0.0, 0.121165268, 0.120708992, 0.152441833, 1.26705885, 7.03220701, 10.1565781, 11.7394562, 12.5243101, 26.2911625, 27.5308762, 34.4655838, 33.3992195, -0.000153284882, 0.000568685425, -4.0209774e-05, 3.89236832e-05, 0.000290123566, -0.00226349735, 2.0346014e-05, -3.14919395e-05, -0.000384720856, -2.75364189e-05, 2.39696522e-05, 8.43503952e-06, 1.46955872e-05, -0.0383211823, -0.0385091896, 0.00271969485, -0.00597921848, 0.0775424423, 0.00357709074, 0.00436138248, -0.00955755329, 8.97015572e-06, -0.137678406, 0.000970456665, -8.64766174e-07, -0.156308731; 187.5, 0.0, 0.118988342, 0.119786552, 0.152369507, 1.24918771, 7.0306282, 10.1524391, 11.7177658, 12.5243092, 26.049839, 27.5282478, 34.4655838, 37.3313332, -0.000151576111, 0.000570432922, 2.22414017e-05, 3.42602654e-05, 0.000287870667, -0.00226369929, 2.21327553e-05, -3.37703247e-05, -0.000384719849, -3.28333435e-05, 2.40614624e-05, 8.43494415e-06, 6.49287128e-06, -0.0378939934, -0.0372608452, -0.00145591199, -0.00542455482, 0.074719574, 0.00335672474, 0.00408232164, -0.00875357533, 7.95372009e-06, -0.080245285, 0.000683899231, 4.3715094e-07, -0.196699677; 190.0, 0.0, 0.116858894, 0.118837822, 0.152297958, 1.23091626, 7.02899122, 10.1479139, 11.6941319, 12.5243092, 24.9532948, 27.5255089, 34.4655838, 43.7087631, -0.000149901413, 0.000571410095, 8.67566872e-06, 3.02129364e-05, 0.000285783508, -0.00226387715, 2.41047344e-05, -3.62895241e-05, -0.000384718781, -3.62359619e-05, 2.40104408e-05, 8.43495083e-06, 3.14631987e-06, -0.0374753189, -0.0359707489, -0.000549157532, -0.0049361062, 0.0719031982, 0.00317143512, 0.00388165021, -0.00817939949, 7.20596743e-06, -0.0537428932, 0.000341564392, 1.62058945e-07, -0.2088992; 195.0, 0.0, 0.112727142, 0.116876053, 0.152152176, 1.19337523, 7.02551937, 10.1374197, 11.639926, 12.5243092, 22.4547005, 27.5198441, 34.4655838, 63.5006485, -0.000146650772, 0.000572308289, 3.85471559e-06, 2.35291004e-05, 0.000282106537, -0.00226414824, 2.87340622e-05, -4.21810608e-05, -0.00038471637, -4.2829483e-05, 2.39550076e-05, 8.43493652e-06, 1.15650666e-06,
  -0.0366626587, -0.0333576317, -0.00022747081, -0.0041120615, 0.0662582474, 0.0028797617, 0.00365292263, -0.00749141979, 6.22078133e-06, -0.0335395622, 0.00014459668, 7.19030685e-08, -0.2181745; 200.0, 0.0, 0.10876281, 0.114828865, 0.151995438, 1.15478432, 7.02172279, 10.1242056, 11.5731678, 12.5243082, 20.1688595, 27.5138836, 34.4655838, 97.7778931, -0.000143526184, 0.000572750549, 2.4388926e-06, 1.82274666e-05, 0.000279082581, -0.00226427436, 3.46423569e-05, -4.95841827e-05, -0.000384713623, -5.03695107e-05, 2.39311123e-05, 8.4349184e-06, 1.23468935e-06, -0.0358815079, -0.030764555, -0.000133495087, -0.00343931985, 0.0605537033, 0.00266271996, 0.00360132694, -0.00721686459, 5.66029549e-06, -0.0255758495, 8.98340149e-05, 4.8260746e-08, -0.220523834]) annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = { 0, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Real [13] omega2={modelDef.y[1], modelDef.y[2], modelDef.y[3], modelDef.y[4], modelDef.y[5], modelDef.y[6], modelDef.y[7], modelDef.y[8], modelDef.y[9], modelDef.y[10], modelDef.y[11], modelDef.y[12], modelDef.y[13]};
// ------
  Real [13] Ba={modelDef.y[14], modelDef.y[15], modelDef.y[16], modelDef.y[17], modelDef.y[18], modelDef.y[19], modelDef.y[20], modelDef.y[21], modelDef.y[22], modelDef.y[23], modelDef.y[24], modelDef.y[25], modelDef.y[26]};
// ------
  Real [13] Ca={modelDef.y[27], modelDef.y[28], modelDef.y[29], modelDef.y[30], modelDef.y[31], modelDef.y[32], modelDef.y[33], modelDef.y[34], modelDef.y[35], modelDef.y[36], modelDef.y[37], modelDef.y[38], modelDef.y[39]};
// ------
  Real [13] damping={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Real [26, 26] ssA = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1;
     - omega2[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, - omega2[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, - omega2[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, - omega2[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[7], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[7], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[9], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[9], 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[10], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[10], 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[11], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[11], 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[12], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[12], 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - omega2[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, damping[13]];
// ------
  Real [26, 1] ssB = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; Ba[1]; Ba[2]; Ba[3]; Ba[4]; Ba[5]; Ba[6]; Ba[7]; Ba[8]; Ba[9]; Ba[10]; Ba[11]; Ba[12]; Ba[13]];
// ------
  Real [3, 26] ssC = [Ca[1], Ca[2], Ca[3], Ca[4], Ca[5], Ca[6], Ca[7], Ca[8], Ca[9], Ca[10], Ca[11], Ca[12], Ca[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     Ba[1], Ba[2], Ba[3], Ba[4], Ba[5], Ba[6], Ba[7], Ba[8], Ba[9], Ba[10], Ba[11], Ba[12], Ba[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Ba[1], Ba[2], Ba[3], Ba[4], Ba[5], Ba[6], Ba[7], Ba[8], Ba[9], Ba[10], Ba[11], Ba[12], Ba[13]];
// ------
  Real [3, 1] ssD = [0; 0; 0];
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput tableInput annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 40}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-60, 40}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput out1 annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {50, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput out2 annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput out3 annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {50, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ssInput annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-60, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));

  Real x[size(ssA,1)] "states";
  Real y[size(ssC,1)] "outputs";

equation 
  der(x) = ssA*x + ssB*{ssInput};
  y = ssC*x + ssD*{ssInput};
  out1 = y[1];
  out2 = y[2];
  out3 = y[3];

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  connect(modelDef.u, tableInput) annotation (
    Line(points = {{-12, 40}, {-60, 40}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
annotation (
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
end ZapuniInterpolation;
```

Not sure if everything works as expected though, as the input is zero (and I didn't understand the actual model). But it should enable you to continue at least.

One limitations compared to the MSL's state-space block is, that no initial conditions are possible.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate response, it is indeed a solution to my problem! I find it quite strange that the standard State-Space block does not allow the usage of non-parameter variables, but I guess every software/coding language should have at least a few quirks.

Comment: For a "standard" state-space, the matrices A, B, C and D are constants and therefore perfectly suited to be defined as a parameter. This also comes with the advantage, that you can edit them in the GUI directly. As you can see, it is not very complicated to extend the concept. Therefore I think it is a good solution.

Comment: I understand where the concept comes from, and indeed, it is not often that one would want to change the matrices of state-space system. And yes, it is easy to extend the concept, now that I know.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Markus' two solutions there is a third solution:

Declare `omega2`, `Ba` and `Ca` as parameters with the modifier `fixed=false` and assign the values to them in an `initial equation` section.

Best regards

Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: This will compute the state-space coefficients from `tableInput` via `modelDef` once at the initialization. Afterwards they will be constant for the rest of the simulation. If this is what shall be achieved - then it is the simpler solution (compared to my answer)...

Comment: Thank you for answering in addition to Markus' solutions. I have tried your suggestion and indeed it also works! Markus' second solution however is slightly more intuitive for the goals I want to achieve with my model.